# Name of the set of points equidistant from a line

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry

I was reading about geometrical shapes in $n$-dimensional Euclidean spaces and programming some objects that would share some of their properties in different dimensions, like $n$-spheres. I had somewhere an infinite cylinder class that was represented as "the set of points equidistant from a line" and realized that I could easily extend this definition and thus some of the operations to $n$ dimensions. However, I didn't manage to find a name for a general class representing an "$n$-infinite-cylinder".

In the end, my definition to generalize the object to $n$ dimensions does not correspond to the usual way shapes are extended to $n$ dimensions. While this can correspond to a cylinder in a three-dimensional Euclidean space, it does not correspond to anything I could find a name for in a four-dimensional Euclidean space.

Is there a name for such an object?

Comment: I dont know of an official name, but the natural step up to 4 dimensions would be a circle along a plane. Topologically $$S^1\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$$

Comment: Much like other such higher dimensional shapes maybe you could use 4-cylinder (much like 4-sphere), but you can also look up the term hyper cylinder